# [[Int]] -> [Int] with multiply

Tags: haskell

I try to learn Haskell and I don't know how to create a function which takes a  list of lists and multiplies each element in this list e.g.

```
[[2,3], [8,3,2], [2,10,1], [2,2,2,2]] -> [6,48,20,16]
```

I try something like this but it doesn't work. If anyone knows how to do this will be really helpfully for me:

```
listOfProductInt :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
listOfProductInt [] = []
listOfProductInt lists = foldl (\y x-> multipleInts x concat) [] lists

multipleInts :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
multipleInts list1 = foldl (\y x -> y * x) 1 list1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple really, you need `map`:

```
map product [[2,3],[8,3,2],[2,10,1],[2,2,2,2]]
```

The `product` function multiplies all elements in a list. It is included in the [Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:product), which is imported by default. In other words, it is normally available.

The `map` function applies that function to each element in the list.

Comment: `product` is not a built-in/primitive. It is just `foldr1 (*)`.

Comment: @Lazersmoke Thanks, updated the answer. It is indeed not built in, but included via Prelude.

Comment: @Lazersmoke `product` is not `foldr1 (*)`, because `product [] = 1`.

Comment: If we are to be 100% technically accurate, it is actually `product = getProduct #. foldMap Product` as defined in [`Data.Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#product), where `#.` is `const coerce` and the Monoid instance of the `Product` newtype multiplies for `mappend` and uses `1` as the identity element. Its actual type is `(Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`.

Comment: @Lazersmoke, that's the default definition of `product`, but for lists it's actually `foldl (*) 1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer a solution with folds only, first a couple of rules of thumb:

- Never use `foldl` (“lazy<sup>†</sup> left fold”), except in very specific circumstances (which you won't encounter until you've long learned the subtleties).
- Use `foldr` (lazy right fold) for deconstructing lists, if the result is *lazy*. In particular, this is usually the right choice if your fold produces a list again: `foldr` will only consume the list by demand, and it doesn't keep a reference to the original head, hence it works smoothly even on infinite lists and avoids memory blowup (in fact, the garbage collector can reclaim parts of the list that are already processed, before the processing is finished!)
- Use `foldl'` (strict left fold) for “atomic” operations like computing the sum of all values in a list.

So let's start with

```
listOfProductInt :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
-- listOfProductInt [] = [] -- no need for that, folds already handle the empty case.
listOfProductInt lists = foldr _ [] lists

multipleInts :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
multipleInts list1 = foldl' _ 1 list1
```

GHC will inform you

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:32:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
    Relevant bindings include
      lists :: [[Int]] (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:18)
      listOfProductInt :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
        (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:1)
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘_’
```

Unfortunately this is not as informtive as usually because both the result and the individual sub-lists have type `[Int]`. I'll annotate the type:

```
           [Int]   -- the sublist we're focusing on
        -> [Int]   -- the result of the future product-computations yet to be done
        -> [Int]   -- the result at this point of the computation
```

Now, for handling the sublist that's on the agenda first, we have `multipleInts`. So, it should look something like

```
listOfProductInt lists = foldr (\l -> _ (multipleInts l)) [] lists
```

to which GHC replies

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:39:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: [Int] (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:34)
      lists :: [[Int]] (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:18)
      listOfProductInt :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
        (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:4:1)
    In the expression: _
    In the expression: _ (multipleInts l)
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
      ‘(\ l -> _ (multipleInts l))’
```

You may recognise `Int -> [Int] -> [Int]`, or generally `a -> [a] -> [a]`, as the signature of the cons-operator `(:)`, and that's what's needed here:

```
listOfProductInt lists = foldr (\l -> (:) (multipleInts l)) [] lists
```

or, using point-free composition,

```
listOfProductInt = foldr ((:) . multipleInts) []
```

Proceed with the implementation of `multipleInts`:

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:7:29:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: a -> a -> a
    Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for multipleInts :: Num a => [a] -> a
               at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:6:17
    Relevant bindings include
      list1 :: [a] (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file9164.hs:7:14)
```

Well, `a -> a -> a` where `a` fulfills a `Num` constraint? That's just the simple product operation!

```
multipleInts list1 = foldl' (*) 1 list1
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>`foldl` is only lazy in the *values*, but not in the spine. In practice, this tends to give you the worst of both worlds: the processor is immediately clogged with having to handle the whole list, but instead of actually doing useful computations, it merely builds up stacks of memory-hogging laziness-thunks.</sub>